Reloading partial view with AJAX
So i have a mesaging system that when a message is sent im currently reloading the whole view to see the new message in the conversation, however, i want to make it so jus the message partial reloads with AJAX as soon as a message is sent.
I've tried doing this and when i return the partial view in the controller, only the partial view returns as flat HTML. My code is as follows:
Controller that currently returns the full view:
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTicketMessage(OverviewTicketSystemModel t)
        {
            t.Ticket.UserID = _securityHelper.CurrentUser.UserId;

            var sendMessage = await _TicketApiClient.CreateTicketMessageAsync(t.Ticket.UserID, t.Ticket.TicketID, t.Ticket.MessageTexts.MessageText);

            OverviewTicketSystemModel vm = new OverviewTicketSystemModel();

            t.Ticket = await _TicketApiClient.GetTicketByIDAsync(t.Ticket.TicketID);

            vm = t;

            return RedirectToAction("DisplayTicketView", vm);

        }

Message partial view that displays the message and holds the reply box which is appended via JS once a row in my Kendo grid is clicked:
<div class="card mt-3 ml-0 pl-0" style="min-height:95vh">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Ticket.TicketID" />
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-4" style="background-color:white; border-bottom:3px solid #f5f5f5; border-top-left-radius:6px; border-top-right-radius:6px;">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Ticket.Subject))
        {
            <p class="mb-0" style="font-weight:bolder; font-size: 20px;">@Model.Ticket.Subject</p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column pb-0" style="max-height: 80vh;">
        <div class="message-container overflow-auto pr-2 flex-grow-1" id="message-container" style="max-height: calc(80vh - 100px);">
            <!-- Display Initial Message -->
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Ticket.Message))
            {
                <div class="follow-up-message @(Model.Ticket.UserID == SecurityHelper.CurrentUser.UserId ? "message-right" : "message-left")">
                    <p>@Model.Ticket.Message</p>
                </div>
            }

            <!-- Display Follow-up Messages -->
            @foreach (var message in Model.Ticket.MessageText)
            {
                <div class="follow-up-message @(message.UserID == SecurityHelper.CurrentUser.UserId ? "message-right" : "message-left")">
                    <p>@message.MessageText</p>
                    @* <p>Created Date: @message.CreateDate</p> *@
                </div>
            }
        </div>

        <!-- Reply Box -->
        <div class="reply-box mt-0" id="message-reply-form">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTicketMessage", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Ticket.TicketID" />
                <div class="form-group position-relative mb-0">
                    <label for="replyMessage"></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Ticket.MessageTexts.MessageText" rows="1" style="min-height: 65px;"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary position-absolute mt-2" style="bottom: 10px; right: 10px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Where is the JS code segment with the AJAX call and attempt to load the return from AJAX to the DOM?  Please edit your question and add in this code segment and explain in further detail what is being returned from AJAX and how it's problematic.
